# 2013 Toyota Highlander tires

Tags: toyota, tires

can I replace p245/65r17 tires on my 2013 toyota highlander,  with 255/60r17 tires?

Comment: Is it AWD or FWD?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. But the tires are 0.5" diameter smaller, so your speedometer will read faster than you are actually going by about 1.7%, unless you also have the computer corrected for the difference in size through programming.

Comment: Actually, if they are smaller, it will read faster (it will take less distance for the tire to make the revolution, therefor the faster reading). The easiest thing for a person to do is check the RPM (rotations per mile) of the two tires and see the difference. You can do it easily on TireRack.com or the like.